# Overriding a background image inline for an element with multiple background?

Tags: html, css

If I have multiple background images in my css:

HTML:

```
<div class="hero" style="background-image:url(/images/<?php echo $hero['image']; ?>)"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero{
  background: 
  url(number.png) 600px 10px no-repeat,
  url(thingy.png) 10px 10px no-repeat,
  url(Paper-4.png);
}
```

How can I override a particular background with a new inline background image (loaded from a database)?

Ideally, I do not wish to redeclare all backgrounds again inline.

Comment: please, add html code and the correct css snippet.

then i've to know why you have so many backgrounds for the same element and when you need to change a background for other.

Comment: Have updated question

Answer (score -1):

i think i get what you want:
Use style tags and insert css into (in the same php page).

```
<style>
.hero{
  background: 
  url(/images/<?php echo $hero['image']; ?>) 600px 10px no-repeat,
  url(thingy.png) 10px 10px no-repeat,
  url(Paper-4.png);
}
</style>
```

Dont forget to delete style on html tag.

this will change the first background.

Comment: How can this work with multiple background images declared in the css?

Comment: if you want "dinamically" change the background with some event, you must use javascript or jquery to reach this at the breakpoint you want. otherwise you must use the code below (edited) to load dynamic background from database.